# How serialize tree data with XMLAGG function in Oracle 11g not duplicate XML tags, with nested struct?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g

I have tree data of type: 1 subject, 2 passport, 2 address it's one entity. 
How serialize to xml tree data with nested xml tags? Data type of:

[image]

When i build xml in clob with XMLAGG i have get such struct with duplicate tags
Example:

```
<xml>
<person>
<title></title>
<document1></document1>
<document2></document2>
<adress1></adress1>
<adress2></adress2>
<adress1></adress1>
<phone1></phone1>
<phone2></phone2>
<phone3></phone3>
<phone1></phone1>
<phone2></phone2>
<phone3></phone3>
</person>
</xml>
```

This is my query on build XML in CLOB:

```
    ---XMLPERSOM
SELECT XMLELEMENT ("Person",
       XMLELEMENT ("ReferenceCode", SBS.ReferenceCode),
       XMLELEMENT ("LastName", SBS.LastName),
       XMLELEMENT ("FirstName", SBS.FirstName),
       XMLELEMENT ("MiddleName", SBS.MiddleName),
       XMLELEMENT ("BirthDate", SBS.BirthDate),
       XMLELEMENT ("BirthPlace", SBS.BirthPlace),
       XMLELEMENT ("sourceCode", SBS.sourceCode),
       XMLELEMENT ("GroupCode", SBS.GroupCode),
--XMLDOCUMENTS       
       XMLELEMENT ("Documents",  
       XMLAGG(
       XMLELEMENT ("Document",
       XMLELEMENT ("Type", DCS.Type),
       XMLELEMENT ("Series", DCS.Series),
       XMLELEMENT ("Number", DCS.NumberID),
       XMLELEMENT ("IssueDate", DCS.IssueDate),
       XMLELEMENT ("IssueAuthority", DCS.IssueAuthority)))),

       XMLELEMENT ("Addresses",
       XMLAGG(
       XMLELEMENT ("Address",
       XMLELEMENT ("Type", ADDS.Type),
       XMLELEMENT ("Location", ADDS.Location),
       XMLELEMENT ("Street", ADDS.Street),
       XMLELEMENT ("PostalCode", ADDS.PostalCode),
       XMLELEMENT ("Country", ADDS.RU),
       XMLELEMENT ("Region", ADDS.Region)))), 
       )      

FROM SUBJECT_SEGMENT SBS
LEFT JOIN DOCUMENT_SEGMENT DCS ON SBS.ID = DCS.SUBJECT_ID
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS_SEGMENT ADDS ON SBS.ID = ADDS.SUBJECT_ID
GROUP BY SBS.ReferenceCode, 
         SBS.LastName, 
         SBS.FirstName, 
         SBS.MiddleName, 
         SBS.BirthDate, 
         SBS.BirthPlace,
         SBS.sourceCode,
         SBS.GroupCode
```

As a result i have duplicate tags or duplicate clob xml. I need have one clob and haven't duplicate tags.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone has three documents and two addresses your query produces 6 rows for this person. This is why values repeat. You can solve it, for instance, using correlated subqueries for documents, addresses and phones, like here:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT ("Person", 
         XMLELEMENT ("ReferenceCode", ReferenceCode), 
         XMLELEMENT ("LastName", LastName),
         XMLELEMENT ("Documents",  
           (select XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT ("Document", XMLELEMENT ("Type", Type), 
                                                  XMLELEMENT ("Number", NumberID)))  
             from doc where referencecode = sbs.referencecode)),
         XMLELEMENT ("Addresses", 
           (select XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT ("Address", XMLELEMENT ("Street", Street))) 
             from adr where referencecode = sbs.referencecode)))
  FROM SBS
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a0c6edccba57dce5e919fb68c1a76acb)</sup>**

Comment: Thanks, my friend! Your correlation subquery really working! Erlier I trying implementation correlation subquery, but my attempts was not successful. I think, what i tired at work) I implimented this is with help additional "CTE" at with construction. I hope what you answer will help other members StackOwerflow!